# How to require a nested json object in Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  extraData: {
    brand: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 255
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 10
    },
   required: true
  }
});
```

However when i execute it I get the following error: "TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `extraData.required`". How can I require the extraData?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**
You can use the [Subdocument](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) apporach

```
const extraDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  brand: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 10
  }
});

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  extraData: {
    type: extraDataSchema, required: true
  }
});
```

Comment: When I was using this approach, I had some issues but finally making 
`extraData: {
    type: extraDataSchema, required: true
  }` 
Instead of 
`extraData: {
    type: Object, of: extraDataSchema, required: true
  }`
worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#required-validators-on-nested-objects), In this link you can find an explanation on how to add `required` to nested properties().
I believe you will need a sub-schema for the nested properties.